# Generic web email address for emal2case routing

Tags: email2case

We have Email 2 case set up but have started using a Doc Scanning solution for customer orders that then forward different outcome notifications to salesforce.

We are having issues identifying the case account name and contact as each email will come from the doc scanning system with the same web email address which is the same globally, the subject line includes the customer name and account number

Is there a workflow rule to change the case contact or web email to a different contact or web email based on the account number in the subject field to allow the email 2 case to populate as if the email was coming from the customers email not the Ebusiness email address?

Answer (score 2):

Email2Case will record values in these fields (see the [Case SObject Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_case.htm?search_text=knowledge))

- `SuppliedCompany`
- `SuppliedEmail`
- `SuppliedName`
- `SuppliedPhone`

These fields can't be updated after the Case is created so the only point of control you have to change these values is in a `before insert trigger` or `before save flow`. Workflows or process builder flows run after the Case is created.

The trigger is important here, especially if you want to send an auto-response to the sender's (real) email.

Depending on your application design, you might be able to use the information in the `Case.Subject` field and manipulate it in a Field Update or Visual Flow to locate the relevant real Contact and then update the Case record accordingly.  Should the parsing be too complex, you can resort to Apex trigger or invocable method.